# npx react-native run-android doenst see any avds

Tags: react-native

When running command
`npx react-native run-android`

I get error:

```
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`.
```

If I type `emulator -list-avds` in powershell I clearly see one emulator up and running. What I`m doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start emulator from android studio or use command prompt to start emulator.
use this link:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NH554nwx0MU

In my case its giving same error `error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of emulator -list-avds`

but as we started emulator already, we can ignore this error and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

According to github issues https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29617

If you have Android virtual devices created, but `emulator -list-avds` outputs nothing.

Try set the ANDROID_SDK_HOME environment variable, following the official [Environment variables](https://developer.android.com/tools/variables) guide.

> Some older tools, such as Android Studio 4.3 and earlier, **do not read ANDROID_USER_HOME**. To override the user preferences location for those older tools, set ANDROID_SDK_HOME to the **parent directory** you would like the `.android` directory to be created under.

The `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` defaults to `$HOME` (current user's home folder), which contains the avd folder.